# toISOString date to date Conversion

Tags: angular

I saved the date to MongoDB using toISOString. Now I want to redisplay that saved date so How can I covert toISOString to normal date and show it on Datepicker?

## I try below.

```
 parseISOString(s) {
        var b = s.split(/\D+/);
        return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0], --b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5], b[6]));
      }
```

### and

```
var startDate = 2018-12-02T18:30:00.000Z
var n= parseISOString(startDate)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: Why not just `var startDate = new Date("2018-12-02T18:30:00.000Z")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to parse your date, you can use **Angular Date Pipe**

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';


@Component({
  ...,
  providers: [ DatePipe ]
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

    ngOnInit() {
       const startDate  = new Date('2018-12-02T18:30:00.000Z');
       const parseDate  = this.datePipe.transform(startDate, 'mediumDate');   

       console.log(parseDate);   // Jan 2, 2019
    }
}
```

> Or you can refer all the date formats here in [Angular Date Pipe Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)
>
> Had created an existing example with DatePipe usage, you can refer it here on my [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-component-date-pipe)

Comment: How can I use 'Custom format options' for the custom date?

Comment: How did parseDate parse 'Jan 2, 2019' as we didn't assign startDate to it?

Comment: @donton apologies, had updated my answer and also added a Stackblitz demo for your reference in relevance to custom format options :)